# Entity with ApplicationUser property, when i use it in a service the property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an entity called CarOwner. Every car owner has a property ServiceAppUser AutoService. When i add a new CarOwner i use Create method in CarOwnerService

In the SSMS every thing looks fine.

But when i hit the Details method and try to get a CarOwner by GetById, in the CarOwnerService  I found a CarOwner with AutoService == null, and a collection of Cars == null

```
public class CarOwner : BaseModel<int>
{
    public CarOwner()
    {
        this.Cars = new HashSet<Car>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Bulstat { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string MRP { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public decimal Obligation { get; set; }

    public string ServiceAppUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ServiceAppUser AutoService { get; set; }
}


public class CarOwnerService : ICarOwnerService
{
    private IRepository<CarOwner> carOwnerRepository;
    private IMapper mapper;

    public CarOwnerService(IRepository<CarOwner> carOwnerRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.carOwnerRepository = carOwnerRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<int> Create(CarOwnerCreateViewModel model, ServiceAppUser user)
    {

        var carOwner = mapper.Map<CarOwner>(model);
        carOwner.AutoService = user;

        await this.carOwnerRepository.AddAsync(carOwner);
        await this.carOwnerRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

        var id = carOwner.Id;

        return id;
    }



    public CarOwner GetById(int id)
    {
        var allCarOwners = this.carOwnerRepository.All();
        var carOwner = allCarOwners.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);

        return carOwner;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CarOwnerViewModel> GetAll()
    {

        var all = this.carOwnerRepository.All().ToList().Select(co => mapper.Map<CarOwnerViewModel>(co));

        return all;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the Repository, without your data layer it's impossible to tell. Also, are you using EF or EF Core? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it sounds like you might be using Entity Framework Core or another ORM, because you mentioned SSMS.

Without seeing your `IRepository` implementation it is difficult to be certain, but generally the problem you describe is because you didn't tell the ORM to include the other parts of your object graph.

For example

```
dbContext.CarOwners
         .Include(c => c.Cars)
         .Include(c => c.AutoService)
         .Select(c => c);
```

Would return all of your objects, with `Cars` and `AutoService` filled in.

**WARNING** Be careful to only `Include` exactly what you need for any call, or you will end up loading way too much data and slowing down your application.

Comment: Thank you very much, so in this case i have to inject the DB in my controller, i can not use my repository right?

Comment: That isn't the case at all. You can still inject your repository. You have a few options. 1) Do the including inside your repository, but be aware this means it will happen for every call, or 2) you may attempt to do the include on the result of your .All() function, but that would bring database details into your controller, partially defeating the purpose of the repository. There are many design patterns available that would let you do both.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is stuid, but this is my first individual project (i'm trying to build my portfolio and gain some work experience) How to do that you said, when my repo is generic and i dont have access to the properties of the TEntity

Answer (score 0):

this is my IRepository, and yes i am using EF Core

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
 where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> All();

    bool Contains(TEntity entity);

    Task AddAsync(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And this is my implementaion of IRepository:

```
public class DbRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly ServiceAppContext context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public DbRepository(ServiceAppContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = this.context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return this.dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> All()
    {
        return this.dbSet;
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Contains(TEntity entity)
    {
        return this.dbSet.Contains(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then yes, you need to use `Include()` on your `dbSet` object to retrieve your child properties. See my answer for an example.